# Get value of text box using jquery in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get value of textbox(name =city and id=city) using jquery , but it is showing "UNDEFINED" in my python code.

HTML CODE:

```
        <input type="text" class="span3" id="city" name="city" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" />
        </div>

        <script src="bootstrap/newjs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/newjs/new.js"></script>
        <script>
             $('#city').typeahead({ 
                    ajax: { url: '/searchmy?city='+$("#city").value, 
                        triggerLength: 1 }

            });
        </script>
```

python code:

```
name=self.request.get('city')
```

Here i am trying to get value of textbox(name=city , id=city),
It is showing UNDEFINED.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code should be `$("#city").val()` instead of `$("#city").value` See jquery doc on [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 1):

Do try this using GET or POST type and see if its working or not.

```
$('#city').typeahead({ 
     ajax: { url: '/searchmy?city='+$("#city").value, 
     type: "GET" //POST
     triggerLength: 1 }

});
```